Remove Weird Shadows in Displacement Heightmaps
I have some shadow errors when creating a 3D maps in blender that I need some help fixing. While in the EEVEE engine, I have a heightmap generated using QGIS that is applied to the plane using the displacement method.  I use the subdivision surface and shade smooth to clean up the elevation profile, then use the world sky settings to add shadow effects, but I still have these weird half circle shadows that are generated.  Was wondering if anyone had some recommendations to clean these weird shadows from the displacement.


Can you provide a capture from up close, showing the wireframe overlay ? right now it's a bit hard to make out what is going on

Two suggestions: go to your plane in edit mode, select all (a) and merge by distance (m). And try more subdivisions. A third suggestion (but just a wild guess), adjust the middle level of the displacement.
